# Laravel Scout error "Undefined class constant 'VERSION'" after installing Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, laravel-scout

I'm working on a project using Laravel 5.6.* and Laravel Scout ^7.1 with Algolia, and I just installed Guzzle 7.0.

Scout and Algolia were working fine before, but now when I try to save a model I'm getting an error in Sentry that looks like this:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Undefined class constant 'VERSION'
```

Looking at the details in Sentry is how I figured out that it's something to do with Guzzle. The error originated from file:

`/vendor/algolia/algoliasearch-client-php/src/Support/UserAgent.php in Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\Support\UserAgent::getDefaultSegments at line 50`

And the code looks like this:

```
if (interface_exists('\GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface')) {
    $segments['Guzzle'] = \GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface::VERSION;
}
```

`\GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface::VERSION` seems to be what's causing the error. Not sure what to do about this. Did I install an incompatible version of Guzzle or something? Can I configure Scout to tell it NOT to try and use Guzzle and default to whatever it was doing before I installed it?

EDIT: Thought maybe if I updated Scout that might fix the issue, so I ran a `composer update laravel/scout`. Still got the same error though.

EDIT 2: Went ahead and just updated everything with Composer. This bug seems resolved now. Just recreated it and did not get the error again.

Answer (score 0):

See the second edit in the original post. Composer update all fixed the problem.